# Minecraft: clear items WITHOUT custom name

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am using emeralds as currency in my adventure map, so they have a custom name and lore. When they are crafted into an emerald block and back into emeralds, the lore and name is gone. I want to add a repeat command block that permanently checks the player's inventory for emeralds WITHOUT the custom name. Is that possible?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: Are you asking about a workaround instead of the actual solution? Why don't you instead try to pretend them from losing their name at all?

Answer (score 0):

Use `clear` command to detect how many emeralds you have, and how many named emeralds you do. If they are different, you have some unnamed emeralds.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible. You just need to check the players inventory and clear the item.

```
/clear [player] emerald 1
```

then you have to put the custom name into it and give it back plus you need to put it on repeat

```
/give [player] minecraft:emerald 1 0 {display:{Name:"[Custom Name]"}}{display:{Lore:["Lore"]}}
```

Comment: That way you'd be constantly clearing and giving one emerald to the player.

Comment: You also swapped `data` and `maxCount`. This command searches for an emerald with metadata 1 (which doesn't exist).

Comment: First I thought that the constant item in your face would be the only downside, which could be solved with entity models, but no, it also has a number of weird effects on single item stacks.